# File Upload & Delete in asp.net

Tags: file, file-upload

How can i upload a file without clicking submit button & also how to delete this uploaded file in asp.net? I can only upload but i can't delete this uploaded file.My CODE BEHIND SOURCE:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void UploadDocument(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fuDocument.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/" + Path.GetFileName(fuDocument.FileName)));
        lblMsg.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file, you can use javascript - there are many examples of this on SO and the web in general. Such as:

https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-with-javascript-and-c/

You say that you "Can't delete" the file. How are you trying to delete it and what happens when you try? If it's an exception, what is the message and stack trace?

Comment: Thanks. I solved the error and delete operation is working.